# Docker stats, memory usage, big difference between OSX and Ubuntu, why?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a C program running in an alipine docker container.   The image size is 10M on both OSX and on ubuntu.

On OSX, when I run this image, using the 'docker stats' I see it uses 1M RAM and so in the docker compose file I allocate a max of 5M within my swarm.

However, on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS the image is also 10M but when running it uses about 9M RAM, and I have to increase the max allocated memory in my compose file.

Why is there a such a difference in RAM usage between OSX and Ubuntu?

Even though we have different OSs, I would have thought once you are running inside a framework, then you would behave similarly on different machines.   So I would have thought there should be comparable memory usage.

**Update:**

Thanks for the comments.  So 'stats' may be inaccurate, and there are differences so best to baseline on linux.  As an aside, but I think interesting, the reason for asking this question is to understand the 'under the hood' in order to tune my setup for a large number of deployed programs.  Originally, when I tested I tried to allocate the smallest amount of maximum RAM on ubuntu, this resulted in a lot of disk thrashing something I didn't see or hear on my Macbook, (no hard disks!).

Some numbers which are completely my setup but also I think are interesting.

1000 docker containers, 1 C program each, 20M RAM MAX per container, Server load of 98, Server runs 4K processes in total, [1000 C programs total]

20 docker containers, 100 C programs each, 200M RAM MAX per container, Server load of 5 to 50, Server runs 2.3K processes in total, [2000 C programs total].

This all points at give your docker images a good amount of MAX RAM and it is nicer to your server to have fewer docker containers running.

Comment: On OS X, `docker stats` vastly underestimates your actual memory usage, since it doesn't include the VM overhead (which Ubuntu doesn't have, since it's using a kernel that can run Docker natively).

Comment: Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac both actually run under a VM and you won't see an exact behavior of few things between all 3 of these platforms. So the best bet is to check on a supported linux env and base your assumption based on this. Even with `CentOS` and `Ubuntu` you may find few differences in how the storage of the containers work

Comment: Thanks Charles, Tarun, updated question with some of your info and some of me just trying out various permutations of my setup.  Some background to why I asked the question.  Thanks again.